# App crash when pushing view controller,[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:`'`-[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'`

App crash when I am trying to push `viewController` from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`

Below is my code in `ViewControllerB`,

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSError *nserror = nil;
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&nserror];
    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (nserror) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prod_img3.png"];
            pro_image.image = image;
        }
        else{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            pro_image.image = image;
        }
        [self doneChecking];
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Error tells that your url parameter is nil. Try to print the url parameter before passing it to dataWithContentsOfURL.

Comment: and ofcourse url is nil...log it before useing it

Comment: I tried but not solved. print value null received. Can I ignore dataWithContents of URL?

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan no you can't ignore. Try the code in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSError *nserror = nil;
    if(url.length == 0)
    {
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prod_img3.png"];
         pro_image.image = image;
    }
    else
    {
           NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&nserror];
           //this will set the image when loading is finished
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if (nserror) {

                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prod_img3.png"];
                 pro_image.image = image;
           }
           else{
                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                 pro_image.image = image;
           }
       }
       [self doneChecking];
    });
});
```